# How does one confirm if my dbcache setting has taken effect via the gui for bitcoin core 0.17?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin.conf

I set dbcache=4000 in my bitcoin.conf file, but where can one confirm if this took affect or not in the gui? I'm on ubuntu 18.

Comment: Have you tried simply checking memory usage during sync?

Comment: you mean with the "free -h" command?

Comment: yes. dbcache sets how much ram is used during the validation process, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: But where can I see it in the Bitcoin client where it shows that its really set? Using free -h doesn't really say fore sure its that application using it or not.

Comment: If it's in the conf file, instead of a command line flag, then I don't think there is a way to know which settings it's using other than verifying that your conf file is working by changing other settings and seeing if they take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run bitcoind you can see it popup on the loading screen. If it shows up here, it will be the same when you run the bitcoin-qt gui wallet too.

[image]